# Unable to print in a procedural macro function declaration in Rust

Tags: rust

I am using a `proc_macro` and want to print some verbose for debugging. The `println!` statement doesn't print anything.

This is the macro call:

```
decl_module! {

    /// The module declaration.
    pub struct Module<T: Trait> for enum Call where origin: T::Origin {
        // A default function for depositing events
        fn deposit_event() = default;

        /// Allow a user to claim ownership of an unclaimed proof
        fn create_claim(origin, proof: Vec<u8>) -> DispatchResult {
            // Verify that the incoming transaction is signed and store who the
            // caller of this function is.
            let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;
            println!("send is: {}", sender);

            // Verify that the specified proof has not been claimed yet or error with the message
            ensure!(!Proofs::<T>::exists(&proof), "This proof has already been claimed.");

            // Call the `system` pallet to get the current block number
            let current_block = <system::Module<T>>::block_number();

            // Store the proof with the sender and the current block number
            Proofs::<T>::insert(&proof, (sender.clone(), current_block));

            // Emit an event that the claim was created
            Self::deposit_event(RawEvent::ClaimCreated(sender, proof));
            Ok(())
        }

        /// Allow the owner to revoke their claim
        fn revoke_claim(origin, proof: Vec<u8>) -> DispatchResult {
            // Determine who is calling the function
            let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;

            // Verify that the specified proof has been claimed
            ensure!(Proofs::<T>::exists(&proof), "This proof has not been stored yet.");

            // Get owner of the claim
            let (owner, _) = Proofs::<T>::get(&proof);

            // Verify that sender of the current call is the claim owner
            ensure!(sender == owner, "You must own this claim to revoke it.");

            // Remove claim from storage
            Proofs::<T>::remove(&proof);

            // Emit an event that the claim was erased
            Self::deposit_event(RawEvent::ClaimRevoked(sender, proof));
            Ok(())
        }
    }
}
```

It is taken from [here](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/build-a-dapp/pallet). I added the following line:

```
println!("send is: {}", sender);
```

I am running a blockchain(Polkadot dApp), in the terminal (or anywhere), I could not see the output message. Note: everything is working fine but I am unable to print.

Comment: Macros do not affect printing in any way. Your problem comes from somewhere else.

Comment: I understand that you don't see an output. But I'm telling you you are not looking in the right direction to solve your issue. The only possible answer to "How to print in a procedural macro function declaration in Rust?" is "The regular way.". Procedural macros don't care about printing so your problem is not caused by procedural macros.

Comment: Does the question seem okay now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This macro call *generates* code that contains a print statement. It does not *run* that code. You will not see the print output until the code is run and you call `create_claim`.

If you want to debug your macro call, there are several [tools](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/mbe-min-debugging.html) for macros-by-example, but I don't know if they also work for procedural macros or if there are equivalents.